# Why is the axis for my program off

Tags: c++

```
    //============================================================================
// Name        : Assignment.cpp
// Author      : Tim Bialecki
// Version     :
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void circle(int x, int y, int radius);
void line(int a, int b, int c, int d);
bool buffer[26][81];
char drawSpace[26][81];

int main() {
    int a = 75;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 4;
    int d = 26;
    /*cout << "please enter an x coordinate for the center of the circle";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "please enter a y coordinate for the center of the circle";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "please enter a value for the radius of the circle";
    cin >> radius;*/

    circle(a, b, c);
    for (int col = 80; col >= 0; col--) {

        for (int row = 25; row >= 0; row--) {
                cout << drawSpace[row][col];
            }
        cout << "\n";
        }
    return 0;
}

void circle(int x, int y, int radius){
    /*if (x + radius >= 81 || y + radius >= 26 || y - radius <= 26){
        cout << "the coordinates provided for the circle will not fit on the screen" << endl;
        return;
    }*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 81; j++) {
            int a = abs (x - j);
            int b = abs (y - i);
            int distance =  pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2);
            int realDistance = pow(radius, 2);
            if (abs(realDistance - distance) <= 3){
                buffer[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 26; m++){
        for(int n = 0; n < 81; n++){
            if (buffer[m][n]){
                drawSpace[m][n] = 42;
            }
            else
                drawSpace[m][n] = 32;
        }
    }
}

void line(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    int intercept = 0;
    double rise = d - b;
    double run = c - a;
    double slope = rise/run;
    intercept = b - (slope*a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 81; j++) {
            int newIntercept = i - (slope*j);
            int test = abs (intercept - newIntercept);
            if (test <= 0)
                buffer[i][j] = true;
            else
                buffer[i][j] = false;
        }

    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 26; m++){
        for(int n = 0; n < 81; n++){
            if (buffer[m][n])
                drawSpace[m][n] = 42;
            else
                drawSpace[m][n] = 32;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a work in progress, but I'm trying to write a program that takes inputs for the coordinates and dimensions of both a line and a circle and prints them out in the terminal window as if it were a 81x26 graph.  I have just supplied sample inputs to test this out, but for some reason the shapes are not printing with the appropriate orientation to what should be the x and y axises.  I have tried a bunch of different ways of trying to fix this problem and have had no luck.  Hoping someone can help. Thanks

Comment: It's strange to see this kind of assignments given for C++. The language deserves a lot better than these, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks OK to me:

```
               ***    
             **   **  
             *     *  
            *       * 
            *       * 
            *       * 
             *     *  
             **   **  
               ***
```

It's not perfectly round because characters are taller than they are wide.

EDIT: That's only the first few rows on my output. Based on the comment and a second look at the code, I think rows and columns are getting mixed up.

```
 for (int col = 80; col >= 0; col--) {
    for (int row = 25; row >= 0; row--) {
            cout << drawSpace[row][col];
        }
    cout << "\n";
    }
```

There's a newline after every "column". Swapping the two `for` lines may produce what you want.

Comment: for me the y-axis is printing as the x-axis and the top of the graph is the y-axis

Comment: You realize that the terminal has upper left corner as 0,0 in this system with rows going down and columns going right